# How to make Search Form Value multilingual without WPML String Translation?

Tags: wordpress, translation, multilingual

In my theme I have a Search Form which looks like this:

```
<form method="get" id="search" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <div>
    <?php $req=''; ?>
    <input type="text" value="Search" name="s" id="s"  onfocus="if(this.value==''){this.value='<?php  _e( 'Search', 'thememagic' );  ?>'};" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Search'};" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />

    </div>
</form>
```

I think the `_e( 'Search', 'thememagic' )` means that if you would use WPML you could easily translate the "Search" string. But what could I do without WPML?

Would it be possible to pass a variable to the search form template without touching the wordpress core functions? Because I'm calling `get_search_form();` in my theme's functions.php within a shortcode function.

I have a simple site with not much content and for most of the purposes Polylang is good enough to make the site multilingual but I'm stuck at translating the "Search" string.

Comment: Maybe with a magnifying glass icon instead of text?

Comment: There already is one but for usability reasons I would also like some text there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since my site is just bilingual I came up with this and it seems to work.
I changed the input line from above with:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo (get_bloginfo('language')=='de-DE')?'Suche':'Search';?>" name="s" id="s"  onfocus="if(this.value==''){this.value='<?php echo (get_bloginfo('language')=='de-DE')?'Suche':'Search';?>'};" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='<?php echo (get_bloginfo('language')=='de-DE')?'Suche':'Search';?>'};" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
```

So if a visitor is from Germany the text is displayed in German and otherwise in English. It's quick and dirty but it works. Still open for more elegant solutions though ;)